# Creating an array of objects with their own properties in Javascript

Tags: javascript

```
var i;


    var Book = new Array();
    var Book[0] = [title: "1984", author: "George Orwell", publisher: "Harvill Secker", price: "€8.99"];
    var Book[1] = [title: "Metro 2033", author: "Dmitry Glukhovsky", publisher: "Orionbooks", price: "€12.99"];
    var Book[2] = [title: "Always Outnumbered, Always Outgunned", author: "Walter Mosley", publisher: "W. W. Norton & Company", price: "€5.99"];    
    var Book[3] = [title: "Journey to the Center of the Earth", author: "Jules Verne", publisher: "Pierre Jules Hetzel", price: "€4.99"];
```

I'm trying to figure out how to make an array of objects that have their own properties but this doesn't seem to work. I can't understand what's going on.

EDIT:

```
    var i;
    var Book = new Array();
    Book[0] = {title: "1984", author: "George Orwell", publisher: "Harvill Secker", price: "€8.99"};
    Book[1] = {title: "Metro 2033", author: "Dmitry Glukhovsky", publisher: "Orionbooks", price: "€12.99"};
    Book[2] = {title: "Always Outnumbered, Always Outgunned", author: "Walter Mosley", publisher: "W. W. Norton & Company", price: "€5.99"};    
    Book[3] = {title: "Journey to the Center of the Earth", author: "Jules Verne", publisher: "Pierre Jules Hetzel", price: "€4.99"};

    for (i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    {
        document.write("Book: " + Book[i].title + "Author: " + Book[i].author "Publisher: " + Book[i].publisher + "Price: " + Book[i].price);
    }
```

This is the updated code. This still doesn't work.

EDIT 2: Was missing a "+" in the document.write.

Comment: Object literal notation uses curly brackets: `{title: '1984',  author: 'George...}`. Square brackets are for array literals.

Comment: use Book[i].author + "Publisher: " instead of Book[i].author "Publisher: "

Answer (score 2):

You are passing array to your arrays, not objects.

1. Change `[` for `{`, since second is proper object definition.
2. Don't use var twice. Once you have variable, you can use it without var.

   ```
   var Book = new Array();

   Book[0] = {title: "1984", author: "George Orwell", publisher: "Harvill Secker", price: "€8.99"};
   ```

You can use it like this:

```
alert(Book[0].title);
```

Comment: Okay I have done this and it still doesn't work and updating the original post. The objects do not print via document.write. Can I not use objects in that?

Comment: it works, but you have lack of + in your document.write parameter. write: Book[i].author +"Publisher: "

Comment: Well. That's a huge mistake. Will update the top post.

Answer (score 0):

The syntax is incorrect.

Array is: [ ]
Object is: { }

Besides the Book variable must be declared once.

The correct way is :

```
 var Book = new Array();
 Book[0] = {title: "1984", author: "George Orwell", publisher: "Harvill Secker", price: "€8.99"};
 Book[1] = {itle: "Metro 2033", author: "Dmitry Glukhovsky", publisher: "Orionbooks", price: "€12.99"};
 Book[2] = {title: "Always Outnumbered, Always Outgunned", author: "Walter Mosley", publisher: "W. W. Norton & Company", price: "€5.99"};    
 Book[3] = {title: "Journey to the Center of the Earth", author: "Jules Verne", publisher: "Pierre Jules Hetzel", price: "€4.99"};
```

Or

```
Book.push ( {title: "1984", author: "George Orwell", publisher: "Harvill Secker", price: "€8.99"}) 
//...
```